# How do i get the last digit of the current year in PHP

Tags: php, string, date

**Y**
A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   Examples: 1999 or 2003

**y**
A two digit representation of a year    Examples: 99 or 03

How about if I want to display only the last digit?

Comment: Use either `Y` or `y` and mod (`%`) the result with 10

Comment: Hi Mark do you have an example code to eliminate the first 3 digit. I want to display only the last digit of the current year.

Comment: you can use `explode()` and use only necessary values

Comment: @ramu how you use explode for "2017" value ?

Comment: explode() need to use array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as @mark Suggest is very simple solution.

```
echo date("y")%10;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

`echo substr($year, -1);`

Comment: I'll use this for long string. Thanks DeadSpace

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$year2=95;
$year4=1995;
$data2=substr($year2, -1);
$data4=substr($year4, -1);
echo $data2;
echo $data4;
```

This will do it. No matter how long the number is it will always return the last digit. You can change '-1' value if you want to show more digits. I just used the 2 forms of the year (4 digits and 2 digits) to show you it works the same for both cases.